# How can I add data, insert rows and delete columns in a CSV file using powershell and then save it?

Tags: powershell, csv, import, export-to-csv

I have a big CSV file with lots of columns and lots of data, now all I am looking to do is delete few of those columns and also insert a row at the very top for the remaining columns and give new column headings.

Example of the CSV file I have and would like to import it in PowerShell:

```
Server A    January  C:drive     Medium  Security  Logged
Server A    March    D:drive     High    Security  Logged
Server B    March    D:drive     High    Audit     Logged
Server B    May      F:drive     Low     Audit     Logged
Server C    May      E:drive     Low     Audit     Logged
```

And I want to use PowerShell/script to get an output like this:

```
Month    Drive       Alert
January  C:drive     Medium
March    D:drive     High
March    D:drive     High
May      F:drive     Low
May      E:drive     Low
```

So basically again,
1) removing unwanted columns.
2) inserting a new row, at the very top.
3) adding new data to the new row.
4) finally exporting the CSV file.

Thanks for the help guys :)

Comment: Just do it manually in a spreadsheet editor :-)

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
    $fileContent=import-csv C:\temp\ddddd.csv -Delimiter ";" -Header Server, Month, Drive, Alert, security, Log | select Month, Drive, Alert 
    $newRow = New-Object PsObject -Property @{ Month = 'December' ; Drive = 'X:drive' ; Alert='Low'}
    $fileContent += $newRow
    $fileContent | export-csv C:\temp\ddddd2.csv -NoType
```

Comment: hey there, thanks, but do you know how I can delete an entire column or a row with powershell? thanks